# Python: How to compare date string in ISO 8601 format with current time

Tags: python, python-datetime, iso8601

```
date_str = '2022-03-29T17:49:35.914417-04:00'
```

How to compare above date string with current date time?

Comment: Parse it with `strptime`, then compare?

Comment: What kind of comparison? Do they share common characters? one is earlier than the other?

Comment: wanted to check if above date_str is earlier or after with current time(consider any timezone)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`datetime.fromisoformat(date_string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) to parse `date_str` and then passing the determined timezone info into [`datetime.now(tz=None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_str = '2022-03-29T17:49:35.914417-04:00'
>>> dt = datetime.fromisoformat(date_str)
>>> dt
datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 29, 17, 49, 35, 914417, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
>>> dt_now = datetime.now(dt.tzinfo)
>>> dt_now
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 20, 15, 50, 58, 525908, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=72000)))
>>> dt_now > dt
True
>>> dt_now - dt
datetime.timedelta(days=51, seconds=79282, microseconds=611491)
```

Comment: Thanks, i was able to compare date_str with current date(passing timezone from date_str)